# How to query overloads instead of getting the statement as a sql string. SQLiteQueryBuilder.setStrict(true)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Android documentation for SQLiteQueryBuilder.setStrict(boolean flag) suggests that in order to get a maximum protection against malicious third party apps the following should  be done:

1. Set this value to true
2. Use a projection map
3. Use one of the query overloads instead of getting the statement as a sql string.

I provided a sample code where I did points 1 and 2, but I don't know how and why to implement the third point.
Also, why the point 1 (set this value to true) is not implemented in Android by default?

@Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[]  selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

`switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case MANY_:
            qb.setTables(MyTable.TABLE_NAME);
            qb.setProjectionMap(projectionMap);
            qb.setStrict(true);
            break;
        case ONE_:
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
    }

    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);

    c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return c;
}`

Comment: Hey, were you able to find an answer?

Comment: I used projection and setStrict(true) in the code, but I'm still not sure what they mean by "Use one of the query overloads instead of getting the statement as a sql string". We are overriding here (no change to type, signature and exception type), not overloading. I use a content provider using the code above and it works without any issues.

Comment: From query overloads it means that you use '?' in your queries as in for delete query :

db.delete(TABLE_NAME,_ID + " = " + rowId + (!TextUtils.isEmpty(selection) ? " AND (" + selection + ")" : ""), selectionArgs);

But I have tried all the methods mentioned by play store. The problem is that they reject my app saying I have a vulnerability for SQL injections in my provider. There might be something you could suggest, Please have a look -

Link to my question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631320/your-apps-are-using-a-content-provider-that-contains-a-sql-injection-vulnerabi