# Your app(s) are using a content provider that contains a SQL Injection vulnerability

Tags: android

I have 2 apps. The second app interacts with the first app through content provider to get some credentials. Today while uploading my apk on playstore I got an error -SQL Injection
Your app(s) are using a content provider that contains a SQL Injection vulnerability.
To address this issue, follow the steps in this [Google Help Center article](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/7668308).

Now I performed all the steps mentioned in the article but still get the same error. The steps specificly being :

If an affected ContentProvider needs to be exposed to other apps:

- You can prevent SQL Injection into SQLiteDatabase.query by using
  strict mode with a projection map. Strict mode protects against
  malicious selection clauses and projection map protects against
  malicious projection clauses. You must use both of these features to 
  ensure that your queries are safe.
- You can prevent SQL Injection    into SQLiteDatabase.update and
  SQLiteDatabase.delete by using a       selection clause that uses '?'
  as a    replaceable parameter and a       separate array of selection
  arguments.    Your selection clause       should not be constructed
  from untrusted    inputs.

My SQLiteQueryBuilder with set strict = true and projection map.

```
    private static final HashMap<String,String> values;
    static {
        values = new HashMap<String, String>();
        values.put("_id", "_id");
        values.put("name", "name");
    }

        @Override
        public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, @Nullable String selection, @Nullable String[] selectionArgs, @Nullable String sortOrder) {
            SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
            qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
            qb.setStrict(true);


        switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
            case uriCode:
                qb.setProjectionMap(values);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
        }

        if (sortOrder == null || sortOrder == "") {
            sortOrder = name;
        }
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null,
                null, sortOrder);
        c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: yes, I have solved the problem.

Comment: @RishabhLashkari Can you share your solution? (I'm having the same problem myself). Thanks!

Comment: @sunyata I had to work around a bit to find the answer. Even though my provider never used update and delete queries I was supposed edit them in a fashion mentioned by pitos. So  there must not be any queries with sql vulnerability, strict mode must be true and you must be using projection map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an answer. (I don't have enough reputation to comment). Looks like the error relates to update and delete only, defined in the content provider. The code above just returns data. I suggest going back to each of your content providers and check:

```
delete(Uri var1, String var2, String[] var3)
update(Uri var1, ContentValues var2, String var3, String[] var4);
```

The TABLE_ID case should have selection and selection arguments defined as you mentioned. In my recent app I defined "=?" in e.g delete, but used .delete(object_Url, null, null) when calling the ContentResolver. If the object_Url matches the id it is parsed and selection arguments are returned e.g

```
selection = CONTRACT._ID + "=?";
selectionArgs = new String[] {String.valueOf(ContentUris.parseId(uri))};
```

Comment: Hi Pitos. Do these changes need to be made inside the ContentProvider class where we override the query,delete and update methods or everywhere in the code where we call these methods? I'm already using ? when I pass selection statements but my app is still rejected in the PlayStore, that's why I'm wondering if I need to change the ContentProvider class itself.

Comment: Only in the class extending ContentProvider, where you override update, delete etc. My app is still working fine in the Google Play. However, if you are still having problems, I suggest switching to Room. It's much easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Pitos. Every time I modify this class my queries just stop working and I've tried over and over again and I cannot figure it out. I know I'm asking a lot but if you could look at my snippet and at least advise me what to do for one of the methods, I'm sure I will figure out others. The test class is here https://gist.github.com/Buli1212/d489e8c67c3fde08e1fd08f30a759e28

Comment: 1. You don't handle an exception in the try/catch in onCreate. 
2. Why not use the content authority from a constant instead? (PROVIDER_NAME in your case).
3. Avoid !! wherever possible

Add break-points to onCreate first and then in each ContentProvider methods

Comment: Thank you for the code review :) I have already tried debugging each method but it doesn't get me any closer to make it SQL Injection safe. I use parameterised queries with arguments when I call these methods but not inside them in the Content Provider class I shared.