# Fixing a SQL Injection Vulnerability on Content Provider Android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have different apps that share some data with each others, that's done through Content Provider but when I uploaded the apk I received an email saying "Your app(s) are using a content provider that contains a SQL Injection vulnerability."

There are a couple of ways for fixing this according to Google guide:

If an affected ContentProvider needs to be exposed to other apps:

- You can prevent SQL Injection into SQLiteDatabase.query by using
  strict mode with a projection map. Strict mode protects against
  malicious selection clauses and projection map protects against
  malicious projection clauses. You must use both of these features to ensure that your queries are safe.
- You can prevent SQL Injection into SQLiteDatabase.update and SQLiteDatabase.delete by using a selection clause that uses '?' as a replaceable parameter and a separate array of selection arguments. Your selection clause should not be constructed from untrusted inputs.

But is not clear to me how to proceed with any of the solutions, I don't get exactly how to use the projection map or change the code using selection clause that uses '?'. I mean, I have seen some examples about ProjectionMap but what are the key/value it needs for the query? Do I need to write explicit the values I want? but what if it is a generic method and I don't know in that part of the code what do I want to get? Or how do I convert any query to a ProjectionMap?

I hope I'm explaining myself on this.

Here is my code:

```
     @Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    gOpenHelper = new GameDBHelper(getContext());
    return true;
}

/**
 * Builds a UriMatcher that is used to determine witch database request is being made.
 */
public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher(){
    String content = GamesContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

    // All paths to the UriMatcher have a corresponding code to return
    // when a match is found (the ints above).
    UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    matcher.addURI(content, GamesContract.PATH_GAME, GAME);
    matcher.addURI(content, GamesContract.PATH_GAME + "/#", GAME_ID);

    return matcher;
}

@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) {

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case GAME:
            return GameEntry.CONTENT_TYPE;
        case GAME_ID:
            return GameEntry.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
}

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = gOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor retCursor;
    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case GAME:
            retCursor = db.query(
                    GameEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    selection,
                    selectionArgs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        case GAME_ID:
            long _id = ContentUris.parseId(uri);

            retCursor = db.query(
                    GameEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                    projection,
                    GameEntry._ID + " = ?",
                    new String[]{String.valueOf(_id)},
                    null,
                    null,
                    sortOrder
            );
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
    retCursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
    return retCursor;
}

@Override
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = gOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long _id;
    Uri returnUri;

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case GAME:
            _id = db.insert(GameEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

            if(_id > 0){
                returnUri = GameEntry.BuildGameUri(_id);
            } else{
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unable to insert rows into: " + uri);
            }
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }

    getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    return returnUri;
}

@Override
public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = gOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rows; // Number of rows effected

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case GAME:
            rows = db.delete(GameEntry.TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }

    // Because null could delete all rows:
    if(selection == null || rows != 0){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    return rows;
}

@Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = gOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    int rows;

    switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case GAME:
            rows = db.update(GameEntry.TABLE_NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }

    if(rows != 0){
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);
    }

    return rows;
}
```

}

Comment: there is this related question but it doesn't have a definitive answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51631320/your-apps-are-using-a-content-provider-that-contains-a-sql-injection-vulnerabi

Comment: I guess the analyzer didn't like the `GameEntry._ID + " = ?"` selection. You can try to write it another way. I currently have no means to confirm it, so please try it and come back to tell us

Comment: Yeah, I saw that question but there was no clear answer indeed. Thanks!, I will check that selection.

Comment: Hi @EduardoArroyo, did you find a solution? If so, do you mind sharing it?

Comment: @BarryBostwick Sorry, a friend of mine helped me on this and I forgot about the post, but I just posted the solution I found, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who can be looking for the answer, it was pretty simpe, I think it was getting hard for me because I wasn't familiar with many concepts about sql on Android.

The problem goes with the queries that require a 'where' clause; in my case update and delete, the things I needed to do in order to fix it was to not use the selection parameter as it is, I needed to do something like:

`GamesContract.Games.GAME_NAME + " = ?"`

`db.delete(GamesContract.Games.TABLE_NAME, GamesContract.Games.GAME_NAME + " = ?", selectionArgs);`

Basicaly the table name + " = ?" selection.

This way you are forcing to update only the needed table and prevent the sql injection to modify any place in your database through that same method.

Comment: Could you update the code in your question to include this solution? I still cannot wrap my head around it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using SQLiteQueryBuilder

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        final SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
        builder.setProjectionMap(buildProjectionMap());
        builder.setStrict(true);
        count = builder.delete(db, selection, selectionArgs);
    }else {
        count = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
```